# For a ring R, does $GL_n(R)$ embed into $GL_m(F)$ for some field F?

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Suppose $R$ is a noncommutative ring. What is the sufficient and necessary condition for $GL_n(R)$ embedding into $GL_m(F)$ for some field $F$?

In particular, what if $R$ is the group ring $\mathbb{Z}D_8$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2[D_8,t^{\pm1}]$, where $D_8$ is the dihedral group of order 8.

Thanks!.

Comment: The ring must be commutative, at least, I presume?

Comment: Do you really mean $GL(R)$ or do you really mean to ask whether $GL_n(R)$ embeds into $GL_m(F)$ (possibly with $m=n$ or something like that?)

Comment: So $F$ is not commutative either? It seems difficult to embed a non-abelian group into a commutative field...

Comment: Then please edit the question to reflect what you are actually asking.

Comment: Well if $R$ was the group ring of nonlinear group then the answer would certainly be no.

Comment: @ToddLeason You're right, I don't know what I was thinking. However, the following should hold: the answer is positive if $R$ embeds in $M_m(F)$ for some $m$ and a field $F$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: I guess your comment would imply a positive solution for $\mathbb{Z}[D_8]$ by embedding in $\mathbb{C}[D_8]$ and using Wedderburn's theorem. Actually, this would imply a positive solution for group rings of finite groups.

Comment: @MatthiasWendt: Sorry, I don’t follow. Which Wedderburn’s theorem exactly do you use here, and how do you apply it to yield an embedding of $\mathbb C[D_8]$ in a matrix ring over a field? Your claim apparently contradicts YCor’s comment.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: I wanted to use Wedderburn's theorem to see that the group algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ is a product of matrix rings (maybe I should have said Maschke's theorem), and then use some block-diagonal embedding into a bigger matrix ring. Probably I made a mistake, but I can't see exactly where the contradiction arises.

Comment: @MatthiasWendt: I see, Maschke’s theorem does make $\mathbb C[G]$ a finite  product of matrix rings over $\mathbb C$, and a block-diagonal embedding should work. So, now I can’t see where the contradiction arises either.

Comment: In particular, $\mathbb Z[C_4]$ should embed as a ring in $M_4(\mathbb Q(i))$ so that the generator of $C_4$ maps to the diagonal matrix with $1,i,-1,-i$ on the diagonal, and $GL_2(\mathbb Z[C_4])$ then embeds in $GL_8(\mathbb Q(i))$ by replacing each entry with the corresponding $4\times4$ block. Where does this go wrong?

Comment: @YCor: I think $C_4^{(\mathbb{Z})}$ embeds into $GL_3(\mathbb{Z}_2[t^{\pm1}])$. Let $a^{(i)}$ be generator of $C_4^{(i)}$. $a^{(i)}$ maps to $\{\{1,t^i,0\},\{0,1,t^i\},\{0,0,1\}\}$.

Comment: My previous (erased) comment was based on a confusion. $C_4\wr\mathbb{Z}$ is indeed linear over a field of characteristic 2.

Answer (score 9):

This question is studied and partially answered in https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.3153. The answer depends not only on $R$ but also on $n$.

Answer (score 6):

I'm really just expanding on other people's comments, so I've made this answer community wiki.

If $R$ is a subring of a finite dimensional algebra over a field $K$ ($d$-dimensional, say), then $R$ embeds in $M_d(K)$  via the regular representation. So $M_n(R)$ embeds in $M_{nd}(K)$, and so $\text{GL}_n(R)$ embeds in $\text{GL}_{nd}(K)$.

This isn't a necessary and sufficient condition (as the much deeper results referred to in Mark Sapir's answer show), but is enough to deal with both examples in the question, since $\mathbb{Z}[D_8]$ is a subring of the finite-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra $\mathbb{Q}[D_8]$, and $\mathbb{Z}_2[D_8,t^{\pm1}]$ is a subring of the finite dimensional $\mathbb{Z}_2(t)$-algebra $\mathbb{Z}_2(t)[D_8]$ (*I think the OP uses $\mathbb{Z}_2$ to mean the integers mod $2$, but if it means the $2$-adic integers, then it's a subring of the finite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}_2(t)$-algebra $\mathbb{Q}_2(t)[D_8]$*).

In particular, even Maschke's theorem isn't needed.